# How to make VIM json syntax highlight more readable

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-json

Using VIM 8.1 in Ubuntu 20.04.02. `~/.vimrc` has `syntax on`. The file `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/json.vim` exists.

While the syntax highlight for YAML file is comparable between VIM and Visual Studio code.
VIM json syntax highlight is not as clear as the one rendered by VSCode. Is there a way to improve VIM json syntax?

[image: JSON syntax, VIM vs VSCode]

Comment: Please, describe in your own words what you feel is wrong with current colors. Pictures are discouraged for good reason.

Comment: The json file displayed in VIM doesn't distinguish the key from the value. When the value is a string. And of course the guidelines (the thin vertical lines) showing the level of indentation is also very helpful. You can also notice hat VSCode goes even further, key at different level have different colors. BTW, Why would pictures be discouraged? without a screenshot it would be very hard to show the difference.

Comment: Pictures are misleading. They could be good as supplement, but not as replacement. For example, at least two of your points are not really about syntax. Please, edit your question, so it could be answered properly.

Comment: I'm okay with the default syntax highlighting. Yeah, it's a little boring. So is json. :P Google "vim syntax json" and I'm sure you'll find a plugin that does what you want. For the indent lines google, wait for it, "vim indent lines". There is at least one plugin I'm aware of that replicates that behavior.

Comment: This plugin and customize further yourself: [vim-json](https://github.com/elzr/vim-json/issues/37)